# SVG font family selection

Tags: browser, svg, fonts, adobe-illustrator

We are using Myriad Pro in an SVG file which is output from Adobe Illustrator. If we use Myriad Pro and set it to Italic in the Illustrator file, the SVG output sets the font-family name of a text element to 'MyriadPro-IT', the filename of the font file, instead of `<text font-family='Myriad Pro' font-style='italic'>Hello World</text>`.

Any ideas of either having browsers understand that the font-family is a file name on the local system (or... sub font? Not familiar with the terminology here).

Thanks!

Comment: Not using Illustrator would be a good start. But a simple search and replace operation in a plain text editor should fix this for you.

Comment: Not using Illustrator is not an option. If Illustrator does this for any single font combination, the so called simple search and replace will obviously become more complicated depending on which fonts the design team feels like using. Yes, a search and replace is the manual backup but was hoping for an automated process.

Comment: There is nothing in the SVG or CSS specs that will allow you to persuade clients to interpret `font-family="MyriadPro-IT"` as `font-family="'Myriad Pro',Myriad,sans-serif"`, which is what you actually need. If you want a systematic solution, then you'll probably have to build your own SVG sanitizer to fix these issues as they arise. Perhaps [xmlsh](http://www.xmlsh.org/HomePage) would be useful for this purpose. Good luck.